# google sheets query filter by datediff is this possible?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, datediff

So i use the following formula:

```
query(OVERVIEW!$B$11:$W;"Select B,C,D,I,G,H,K where month(C)="&0+$D$11&"and W matches '"&IF($B$10=TRUE;"CREATE PO";"")&"' Order by "&$B$3&"")
```

and what it does it checks in which month you are looking and based on the forecast it will check a couple of months and return the result in the table.

So for this example, lets say I have 12 monthly tables

Jan Feb Mar Apr Mei Jun Jul Aug Sep Okt Nov Dec

I want data to be filled under each table + forecast of 3 months

So in Jan, I get Mar orders for example. this works as it is now but if go to let's say
Okt it should give me 3 months later data so in Jan next year only the formula I have does it for this year only and if I remove the year part I get both years Jan and that is not what I want. it should count furter so Dec 2021 + 3 months will be Marth 2022.

Any pointers?
I was thinking something with Datediff en EOMONTH() functions??
[Example what needs to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTfRn.png)

UPDATE: Link to file:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ti7TdF2mWEGxA1E4FIeNJ7sEEtYTgu4UQtMxYqS7ets/edit?usp=sharing

Update I have created a working example in the second tab with the
following formula:

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(C4:C22,"select * where C >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(EOMONTH("01-01-"&E1,D1-1)+1),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'and C <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(EOMONTH("01-01-"&E1,D1)),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))
```

i do not know if this is the best solution but it works XD

Comment: I have put a link to the file :P

Comment: i think i have a working solution in the second tab

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR(QUERY(C4:C22,"select * where C >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(EOMONTH("01-01-"&E1,D1-1)+1),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'and C <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(EOMONTH("01-01-"&E1,D1)),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))
```

pasting the above code in each column and change the month to the same month you need for example Feb is "01-02"